# Get the functionality of a Webpage into an iOS App - Swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift

Is it possible to have an HTML website, coded with JavaScript and get the functionality of this website into my App with WebKit or something else?

With WebKit or WebViews it is possible to load a whole Webpage into my app, so the functionality is automatically there, too.

But isn't there a way to change the UI in the app?

For example, there is an HTML-Webpage which represents a table, with some information. 
Above the table are 3 text fields, depending on what you type into the text fields the information in the table changes.

Is it possible to load this web page into my app and change the table in some way? Like creating a whole new app based on this web page?

Comment: yes its possible you can write entire html code and then just pass html into webview

Comment: I mean there is already an existing web page and I want the functionality of this(which is written in JS(JavaScript)) web page and have my own UI in iOS

I do also have the JavaScript-code from this web page

Comment: if you have already host your website then simply by passing url did the work

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) is Apple's latest API for displaying websites (built on top of WebKit).  If you do not want to display the webpage in your app and instead run your own custom UI, you can look into Apple's [Javascript Core](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) .  This framework allows you to run native Javascript functions within your iOS App without having to load any web pages.  WKWebView also has function called:

`func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, 
      completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)`

That allows you to alter the contents of the webpage based on the javascript that is passed in.